# How to use ng-class compare to self invoked value

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Hi I have been using this tag to change my css style, if the condition totalAsset and sortedAsset are same

```
<div class="table-row" ng-repeat="x in myData" 
ng-model="sort(x.totalAsset)" 
ng-class="{'lightblue': x.totalAsset == sortedAsset}">
```

totalAsset is my data in like this

```
$scope.myData = [
{
totalAsset: "23557"
},
{
totalAsset: "4512190",   
},
{
totalAsset: "2190",   
},
{
totalAsset: "1256790",   
}
]
```

i have create a function that self sort the totalAsset

```
$scope.sort = function(totalAsset) {

$scope.unsortedAsset = totalAsset;
$scope.sortedAsset = $scope.unsortedAsset.split("").sort().join("");
console.log(sortedAsset);
}
```

in the logic only the first and last row will become blue the other two rows remain same.

But my problem here is only the last one become blue, the first one doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about, if you need the {{ }}( they are not needed in ng2 atleast ).

```
<div class="table-row" ng-repeat="x in myData" 
ng-model="sort(x.totalAsset)" 
ng-class="x.totalAsset == sortedAsset ? 'lightblue' : ''">
```

Second approach is to do the if in controllers function

```
$scope.areValuesEqual() {
if($scope.x.totalAssets == $scope.sortedAssets) {
return 'lightblue';
}

return; 
}
```

But this looks rather ugly, but i am just throwing this out there.

Comment: Also one reason the ng-class is not working is that the x.totalAssets and sortedAssets are not equal. You should check that first.

Comment: so for the second controller function, how do I write it to make things work this way?`ng-class=areValuesEqual()` ?

Comment: Just like you wrote: `ng-class="areValuesEqual()"`

Comment: I wrote the function but the function doesn't execute the if case..`$scope.sort = function(totalAsset) {
    
    $scope.unsortedAsset = totalAsset;
    console.log(totalAsset);
    $scope.sortedAsset = $scope.unsortedAsset.split("").sort().join("");
    console.log($scope.sortedAsset);
    for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
      if(totalAssets == $scope.sortedAssets) {
          console.log("1");
          return 'lightblue';
      }
      console.log("0")
      return; 
      
      };
    }` here is what I wrote in function

Comment: This is unreadable, update your post and add the code to the bost.

Comment: Or post it in patebin